# yii2 change password logic using advanced template

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to get changing the user password when a certain number of days have passed since the last change of password working in the advanced template of Yii2.

The flow should be as follows:
- user logs in
- when login succesful scheck the number of days since the password has been changed
- if more than n number of days present form to change password
- change password form requires current password, new and vaildation password and submit button
- validate against password requirements and save password

Sofar I have used the standard SiteController logic to login the user. In the actionLogin section I have included the logic to test for the number of elpased days and trigger changing the password.
The changePasswordForm is displayed, but upon completion old password is not checked against the current password. Control is passed back into the action Login, the variable $intervalDagen remains NULL and therefore the user returns to the index page and the message 'Kan niet nogmaals inloggen.' ('Cannot login again') is displayed.

I tried first to include all logic in the action Login but that failed equally, so therefore I tried triggering the actionChangepassword.

So, my problems are that the validation checks in the model changePasswordForm are never executed, and the valued of $intervalDagen is not retained.
As, you will see, I have not implemented code for actually changing the password yet, since I cannot obtain the value of the new password yet.

SiteController:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        static $intervalDagen;

        echo '<p>$intervalDagen<br /></p>';
        var_dump($intervalDagen);

        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && $intervalDagen <= 60) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('failure', 'Kan niet nogmaals inloggen.');
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new GebruikerLoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login())
        {
            $epoch = Yii::$app->user->identity->updated_at;
            $dt = new \DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
            $laatstBijgewerkt = strtotime($dt->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
            $vandaag = strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
            $intervalSeconden = $vandaag - $laatstBijgewerkt;
            $intervalDagen = intval($intervalSeconden / 86400);

            if ($intervalDagen > 60)
            {
                $modeluser = Gebruiker::find()->where([
                    'username'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->username
                ])->one();

                $changePasswordc = Yii::$app->createController('site');

                $passwordChanged = $changePasswordc[0]->actionChangepassword($modeluser);
                echo $passwordChanged;

                if ($passwordChanged)
                {

                }
                else{

                }

            }

            //return $this->goBack();
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

model changePasswordForm:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: Ynze
     * Date: 23-1-2017
     * Time: 21:08
     */

    namespace common\models;

    use Yii;
    use yii\base\Model;
    use kartik\password\StrengthValidator;

    class ChangePasswordForm extends Model{
        public $oldpass;
        public $newpass;
        public $repeatnewpass;

        public function rules(){
            return [
                [['oldpass','newpass','repeatnewpass'],'required'],
                ['oldpass','findPasswords'],
                ['repeatnewpass','compare','compareAttribute'=>'newpass'],
                [['newpass'], StrengthValidator::className(), 'preset'=>'normal', 'userAttribute'=>'username']
            ];
        }

        public function findPasswords($attribute, $params){
            $user = Gebruiker::find()->where([
                'username'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->username
            ])->one();

            $password = $user->password;
            if (!$user->validatePassword($attribute))
                $this->addError($attribute,'Huidig wachtwoord is onjuist');
        }

        public function attributeLabels(){
            return [
                'oldpass'=>'Huidig wachtwoord',
                'newpass'=>'Nieuw wachtwoord',
                'repeatnewpass'=>'Herhaal nieuw wachtwoord',
            ];
        }

        /* hier de functies om het huidige wachtwoord te controleren en de nieuwe vervolgens op te slaan */
        public function checkSetPassword()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

view changePassword:

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use kartik\password\PasswordInput;

    $this->title = 'Wijzig wachtwoord';
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="site-changepassword">

    <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">

    <h2><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h2>

    <p>Vul de volgende velden in om het wachtwoord te wijzigen :</p>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'=>'changepassword-form',
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL,
        'fieldConfig'=>[
            'template'=>"{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">
                {input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-5\">
                {error}</div>",
        'labelOptions'=>['class'=>'col-lg-2 control-label'],
        ],

    ]); ?>

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12">

            <div class="row">
                <?= $form->field($model,'oldpass',['inputOptions'=>[
                    'placeholder'=>'Huidig wachtwoord'
                    ]])->passwordInput() ?>
            </div>
            <!--
            < ?= $form->field($model,'newpass',['inputOptions'=>[
                'placeholder'=>'New Password'
            ]])->passwordInput() ?>
            -->

            <p />

            <div class="row">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'newpass', ['inputOptions'=>[
                    'placeholder'=>'Nieuw wachtwoord'
                    ]])->widget(PasswordInput::classname(), [
                    'pluginOptions' =>
                        [
                            'showMeter' => true,
                            'toggleMask' => false
                        ]
                    ])
                ?>
            </div>

            <p />

            <div class="row">
                <?= $form->field($model,'repeatnewpass',['inputOptions'=>[
                    'placeholder'=>'Herhaal nieuwe wachtwoord'
                ]])->passwordInput() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-12">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Wijzig wachtwoord',[
                'class'=>'btn btn-primary'
            ]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```